# Can't access code inside AngularJs controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something really stupid, but for some reason code inside my controller is not being read.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="libraries/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
    <!--<meta charset="UTF-8">-->
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="app1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app1', []);
```

**mainCtrl.js**

```
console.log('out'); // Working
angular.module('app1').controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    console.log('in'); // Not working
}]);
```

Comment: You haven't told angular when to use that controller. Either use the `ng-controller` directive or use `ui-router` and setup some routes, which you can define with corresponding controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to assign on what controller to be used..

```
<body ng-app="app1"><div ng-controller="mainCtrl"></div></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<script src="libraries/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libraries/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="app/app.js"></script>
 <script src="app/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script> 
<!--<meta charset="UTF-8">--> 
</head> 
<body> 
<div ng-app="app1" ng-controller="mainCtrl"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your '`ng-app`' and assign `as many controllers` as you want, like below:-

```
 <body  ng-app="app1">
    <div class="main" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <p>Stuff here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="def" ng-controller="defController">
        <p>Other stuff here</p>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple.Create ng controller.

```
       <div ng-app="app1">

       <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
       <p>
       First Name
        <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" />
       </p>
       <p>
        Last Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="lastName" />
        </p>
        <p>
        Full Name: 
        {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
        </p>
       </div>
       </div>
```

Script:

```
 angular.module('app1', []);

 console.log('out'); // Working
 angular.module('app1').controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 
 function($scope, $http){
 alert('in'); // Not working

 $scope.firstName = "John";
 $scope.lastName = "Doe";
 }]);
```

check:http://jsfiddle.net/dq8r196v/511/